# How to check the condition using xls file in php

Tags: php, filereader, phpexcelreader

Here i am using xls file reader in php it is working fine,i have make one logic,xls file i am geting the badge number(4565) and month(01-2017) now i want check the if the badge number and month already data exist or not , suppose data is exixts means i should not allow to insert the new record,suppose not exits means i want allow to insert the new record, how can do this , i am confusing because of xls sheet.

```
<?php
include 'excel_reader.php';// include the class
$groupfile ='test.xls';
$excel = new PhpExcelReader;
$excel->read($groupfile);
function sheetData($sheet) {
    $result = ''; 
    $row = 2;
    while($row <= $sheet['numRows']) {
        $id = isset($sheet['cells'][$row][1]) ? $sheet['cells'][$row][1] : ''; 
        $loan_month = isset($sheet['cells'][$row][2]) ? $sheet['cells'][$row][2] : ''; 
        $badge_number = isset($sheet['cells'][$row][3]) ? $sheet['cells'][$row][3] : '';
        $name = isset($sheet['cells'][$row][4]) ? $sheet['cells'][$row][4] : '';
        $pf_amount = isset($sheet['cells'][$row][5]) ? $sheet['cells'][$row][5] : '';
        $loan_amount = isset($sheet['cells'][$row][6]) ? $sheet['cells'][$row][6] : '';
        $date_format=date('d/m/Y');
        $status=0;
        $explode_date=explode("/",$loan_month) ;
        $month = $explode_date[1].'-'.$explode_date[2] ;
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO loan_history(pf_month,badge_number,first_name,pf_amount,loan_amount,reg_date,status)VALUES('$month','$badge_number','$name','$pf_amount','$loan_amount','$date_format','$status')");
        if($sql){
            echo "success" ;
        }else{
            echo mysql_error();
        }  
        $row++;
    }
}
$nr_sheets = count($excel->sheets);
for($i=0; $i<$nr_sheets; $i++) { 
    sheetData($excel->sheets[$i]);
}
?>
```

Comment: So there is a table in the DB where "badge_number" and "month_year" are primary columns?

Comment: My requirement is same month and same badge_number then only i want to stop ,suppose same badge_number but month is different means i want to insert the values how can do this

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong, but I understand that the constraint you have makes it perfect to make a multiple column primary key on the table.

1. You make a new constraint on the table:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE foo
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_badge_month PRIMARY KEY (badge_number, month)
   ```
2. Now you can do what we call an upsert, it's much better performing than reading and deciding if we need to update or insert.

   ```
   INSERT INTO foo (badge_number,month,other_column) VALUES (1,'one','won'), (2,'two','too')
   ```

Comment: My requirement is same month and same badge_number then only i want to stop ,suppose same badge_number  but month is different means i want to insert the values how can do this

Comment: See edited, basically if you have de DB manage this for you your life will be easier. That's in case you have access to the DB and can manage it

Comment: Can u please update my answer,i am not able to get you please

Comment: Can you modify the database table structure or constraints?

Comment: I didn't change anything because unique badge_number can insert multiple times in different month

Comment: It's pretty hard to help if you can't understand what I'm saying to you. Sorry